# How to stop coercing text to numeric for specific column

Tags: r, readxl, rasterstats

I have `xsl` sheet with 21 columns, one column contains postal code which should be a factor rather than numeric but before I can convert it into a factor the `read_xsl` function is coercing the Postal codes like `05408` to `5408` as a numeric how can I stop this from happening or change back the codes with `0****` to their original form.

I tried `read_xsl(data, coltypes = 'text')` but all the columns are converted to text so how can I stop this from happening? (Dataframe is too big to be provided)

Comment: you can either read in all your columns as `text`, and post-process to the correct type. Or enter coltypes explicit, i.e. a vector with length 21. One type for each column (assuning your are using `readxl::read_xls()`

Comment: I'm assuming you mean xls, not xsl

Comment: Yes, It is `xls` not `xsl`

Comment: If I read columns as `text` then the dates would be converted into some number which I don't want happening and there are 21 columns I don't want to type for all of them. Is there a function I can use to convert the codes with length 4 to code of length 5 by adding a 0 in front of Postal code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `coltypes = 'text'` use `col_types = c('text', ...)` and define the type of **every** column inside the vector.